# STL set and map for the same user defined type

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class for which I have defined comparison operator. Following is the code I wrote

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <list>

    template <typename _TyV>
    class Element {
    public:
        Element(_TyV in) :  m_Label(in){}
        ~Element() {}
        bool operator < ( const Element & right) const {
            return m_Label < right.m_Label;
        }
    private:
        _TyV m_Label;
    protected:
    };
    typedef Element<int> ElementType;

    int main ( int argc, char **argv) { 
        std::set<ElementType> mySet;
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mySet.insert(ElementType(i));
        }
        std::map<ElementType*, std::list<ElementType*> > myMapList;
        return 0;
    }
```

I am confuse on how my `std::map` will work since the element I am interested in the `std::map` is pointer to the `ElementType`. What I actually want is to store actual data in `std::set` and use pointers to these element in the `std::map`

Major confusion is around the `less than operator`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your map, `std::map<ElementType*, std::list<ElementType*> >` uses `std::less` on the key type as its comparator, as normal.

`std::less` for pointer types is defined to produce a consistent ordering, but the ordering is based on the *address only*, not on anything that it might point to.

So, your set sorts its contents according to the `operator<` in `Element`, but the map sorts them according to the actual pointer value of the key. That probably isn't what you want: (1) it makes different `Element<int>` objects containing the same `m_Label` value act as different keys in the map, and (2) it means the map will be in a different order from the set. But `std::map` can take an extra template argument to provide a comparator, so you can change that.

You could write a comparator that takes two pointers, and compares the objects they point to. This assumes of course that once you've used a pointer as a key in the map, you ensure that the object it points to sticks around (in the `set`, I assume, but if not then insert boilerplate lecture about `shared_ptr` here). Since `Element<int>` is cheap to copy, it would almost certainly be better to use `ElementType` as the key instead of `ElementType*`. But if `int` is just standing in for something you'll use in future that's expensive to copy, then change the `map` comparator.

You might not care about the order of elements in the `map`. If you don't, and if the only things you ever look up in the `map` are pointers to objects in the `set`, then using `ElementType*` as the map key without specifying a comparator should be fine.

Comment: ElmentType in the example is cheap, but I want my Library to handle heavy and big objects also and trying to figure out option to avoid un-necessary copies. Based on your explanation, Do you think I can have std::map of iterator also. i.e. key to the map will be iterator in the std::set

Comment: @Avinash: No, `set::iterator` isn't a random-access iterator, so it doesn't have `operator<` (or a `std::less` specialization).

Comment: @Avinash: `set::iterator` isn't a random-access iterator, so it doesn't have `operator<` (or a `std::less` specialization). You could use it if you provide a comparator.

Comment: @Avinash: drat, you beat me to it, I was just correcting myself!

Comment: ok thanks, I am thinking that both iterator or pointer will be same from memory wise , can you confirm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3817/discussion-between-avinash-and-steve-jessop)

Comment: @Avinash: you'd have to check `sizeof(ElementType*)` and `sizeof(std::set<ElementType>::iterator)` on the implementations you care about, they aren't guaranteed to be the same size. The iterator should be "small", though.

Comment: k thanks, I am thinking that both iterator or pointer will be same from memory wise , can you confirm